# Is it okay if I open the door?

Tags: grammar

1. Is it okay if I open the door?
2. Is it okay to open the door?
3. Is it okay opening the door?

---

Are the three sentences grammatical? In each sentence what does 'it' refer to?

1. It refers to 'if I open the door'.
2. It refers to 'to open the door'.
3. It refers to 'opening the door'.

Is this explanation correct?

Comment: #3 isn't idiomatic in normal contexts (but *Is opening the door okay?* is fine). #2 potentially has a different meaning to #1 (speaker might specifically be asking if it's okay for *someone else* to open the door).

Comment: I don't understand the close votes.  While the question could use more detail, it seems like there is enough to write a reasonably good answer.

Answer (score 1):

As FumbleFingers says, the first two are fine but have slightly different meanings, since with #2 it's not clear *who* should open the door.  #3 would be better phrased as:

> Is opening the door okay?

In all three cases the "it" is an example of the [existential or "dummy" pronoun](https://www.brighthubeducation.com/english-homework-help/60131-existential-there-and-dummy-it-pronouns/) that doesn't really refer to anything.  These pronouns are very common in English, and **it** is best if you just think of them as a kind of punctuation.  You may even have something similar in your own native language.

(In case it isn't obvious, the "it" in the above "it is best" is another example of the existential pronoun).